# Showing that $\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{F_{2^n+1}L_{2^n+1}}\right)=\frac{3}{\phi^2}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, closed-form, infinite-product, golden-ratio

Infinite product

$F_{n}:=[1,1,2,3,5,8,\cdots]$ and

$L_{n}:=[1,3,4,7,\cdots]$

for $n=1,2,3,\cdots$ respectively.

$\frac{1+\sqrt5}{2}=\phi$

Show that,

$$\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{F_{2^n+1}L_{2^n+1}}\right)=\frac{3}{\phi^2}$$

---

We took the idea from this [site](http://home.earthlink.net/~jsondow/)

Expand the product

(1)

$$\left(1+\frac{1}{F_{3}L_{3}}\right)\cdot\left(1+\frac{1}{F_{5}L_{5}}\right)\cdot\left(1+\frac{1}{F_{9}L_{9}}\right)\cdots=\frac{3}{\phi^2}$$

$F_{n}=\frac{\phi^n-(-\phi)^{-n}}{\sqrt5}$

$L_{n}=\phi^n+(-\phi)^{-n}$

$F_{n}L_{n}=\frac{\phi^{2n}-(-\phi)^{-2n}}{\sqrt5}=F_{2n}$

Rewrite (1)

$$\left(1+\frac{1}{F_{6}}\right)\cdot\left(1+\frac{1}{F_{10}}\right)\cdot\left(1+\frac{1}{F_{18}}\right)\cdots=\frac{3}{\phi^2}$$

Still doesn't help much to get from LHS to RHS.

We have $F_{2n}=F^2_{n+1}-F^2_{n-1}$

I have substituted in, but the formula seem too messy and more complicated.

Can anybody please give a hand?

Comment: $F_{4k+2}+1=F_{2k+2}L_{2k}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**. One may use the following result,

> $$
> \prod_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(1+\frac{F_b}{F_{2^na+b}}\right)=\frac{1-(-1)^b\phi^{-2a-2b}}{1-\phi^{-2a}} \tag1
> $$

which is proved by J. Sondow [here (see proposition 1 on page 3)](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1106.4246.pdf), where $\phi=\dfrac{1+\sqrt5}{2}$ and where $F_{n}:=[1,1,2,3,5,8,\cdots]$  are the Fibonacci numbers.

Applying $(1)$ with $a=2$, $b=2$ using $F_{2^n+1}L_{2^n+1}=F_{2^{n+1}+2}$ gives the announced infinite product.

Comment: @mahdi This is a pretty particular case from Sondow's general result. You should send it to him ;).

Comment: Thank you @Olivier OLoa you makes it look so simple. I will send it to him see what he will say.

Answer (score 1):

Use $$F_{4k+2}+1=F_{2k+2}L_{2k}\tag{1}$$ with $k=2^{n-1}$. Also note $$\prod_{k=1}^{n}L_{2^{k}}=\prod_{k=1}^{n}\phi^{2^k}+(-\phi)^{-2^{k}}=\frac{\phi^{2^{k+1}}-(-\phi)^{-2^{k+1}}}{\phi^2-(-\phi)^{-2}}=\frac{F_{2^{k+1}}}{F_{2}}\tag{2} $$ From $\text{(1)}$, note that  $$\left(1+\frac{1}{F_{6}}\right)\cdot\left(1+\frac{1}{F_{10}}\right)\cdot\left(1+\frac{1}{F_{18}}\right)\cdots \left(1+\frac{1}{F_{2^{k+1}+2}}\right)=\frac{F_{4}L_{2}L_{4} \dots L_{2^k}}{F_{2^{k+1}+2}} $$ Using $\text{(2)}$, we have $$\frac{F_{4}L_{2}L_{4} \dots L_{2^k}}{F_{2^{k+1}+2}}=\frac{3F_{2^{k+1}}}{F_{2^{k+1}+2}}$$
But $$\lim_{k \to \infty}\frac{3F_{2^{k+1}}}{F_{2^{k+1}+2}}=\frac{3}{\phi^2}$$

Comment: Yes thank you @MXYMXY, different approach.